# Amazon EMR Spark Cluster: output/result not visible

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I am running a Spark cluster on Amazon EMR. I am running the PageRank example programs on the cluster.

While running the programs on my local machine, I am able to see the output properly. But the same doesn't work on EMR. The S3 folder only shows empty files.

The commands I am using:
For starting the cluster:

```
aws emr create-cluster --name SparkCluster --ami-version 3.2 --instance-type m3.xlarge --instance-count 2 \
  --ec2-attributes KeyName=sparkproj --applications Name=Hive \
  --bootstrap-actions Path=s3://support.elasticmapreduce/spark/install-spark  \
  --log-uri s3://sampleapp-amahajan/output/ \
  --steps Name=SparkHistoryServer,Jar=s3://elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar,Args=s3://support.elasticmapreduce/spark/start-history-server
```

For adding the job:

```
aws emr add-steps --cluster-id j-9AWEFYP835GI --steps \
Name=PageRank,Jar=s3://elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar,Args=[/home/hadoop/spark/bin/spark-submit,--deploy-mode,cluster,--master,yarn-cluster,--class,SparkPageRank,s3://sampleapp-amahajan/pagerank_2.10-1.0.jar,s3://sampleapp-amahajan/web-Google.txt,2],ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE
```

After a few unsuccessful attempts... I made a text file for the output of the job and it is successfully created on my local machine. But I am unable to view the same when I SSH into the cluster. I tried FoxyProxy to view the logs for the instances and neither does anything show up there.

Could you please let me know where I am going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you writing the text file locally?  Generally, EMR jobs save their output to S3, so you could use something like `outputRDD.saveToTextFile("s3n://<MY_BUCKET>")`.  You could also save the output to HDFS, but storing the results to S3 is useful for "ephemeral" clusters-- where you provision an EMR cluster, submit a job, and terminate upon completion.

Comment: Thanks Timothy! I had tried it earlier and it had worked. I was incorrectly thinking it was an error in the cluster initiating commands. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

> "While running the programs on my local machine, I am able to see the
>   output properly. But the same doesn't work on EMR. The S3 folder only
>   shows empty files"

For the benefit of newbies:

If you are printing output to the console, it will be displayed in local mode but when you execute on EMR cluster, the reduce operation will be performed on worker nodes and they cant right to the console of the Master/Driver node!

With proper path you should be able to write results to s3.